# Trouble Connecting a 5G CPE Modem/Router to my DD-WRT Router (LAN to WAN with DMZ)

Tags: router, lan, dd-wrt, wan

I am having some trouble connecting my ISP Provided 5G CPE to my DD-WRT router.
My ISP Provided 5G CPE has no option to be Modem only mode. (Spoke with ISP, they will not enable Modem only mode...its not an option.

I need to maintain my DD-WRT settings to keep my VPN and Ad-Blocking features working.

As i understand, LAN to WAN is the best option with a DMZ pointing at the DD-WRT. This will essentially make the 5G CPE as Modem only as it can be.

Im not fantastic with IP, and i really dont know exactly what to do. I browsed the web, and this was my best attempt.
It did not work!

**Cabling**

I connected the 5G CPE LAN1 to DD-WRT WAN port via CAT cable.

**CPE Config**

I disabled all the firewall parts.
https://ibb.co/hVkbCmm

I set the LAN IP to its own subnet, and left the DHCP on.
https://ibb.co/j3RqX14

I added the DMZ and pointed it at the DD-WRT router. (Now this IP is pre-defined, ie, i do not set it. The CPE seems to pick up the IP from the MAC)
(But you'll notice the IP was actually 192.168.1.2   -  i was expecting this IP to be the Local IP or Gateway of the DD-WRT 192.168.2.1 or 192.168.2.2 ?)
https://ibb.co/2860WKv

In the CPE Online devices, i can see a connection with the DD-WRT
https://ibb.co/bNSrnXp

**DD-WRT Router Config**

I set the operating mode to Router (Previously it was connected to an ADSL Modem and set as Gateway)
https://ibb.co/M6GB077

I set the WAN Connection type to Static IP. I had some difficulties here, i really wasnt too sure what it should be or if it was required. My options here were Disabled, Static, Auto DHCP)

I pointed this towards the CPE IP addresses

https://ibb.co/MCH13Dh

I setup the Network Config, which i beleive is for the local DD-WRT. I just used a different subnet than the Huawei CPE. Again this part i was flaky on.

https://ibb.co/MCH13Dh

I beleive im close to getting it to work, i think i made a simple error in the WAN config through lack of basic IP understanding.
Appreciate someones help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should bridge the two devices. Lan to wan isn't what you want here. Double nat, even DMZed isn't ideal. I can write an answer later this afternoon if you want...

Comment: I was unable to bridge the two devices. The network provided CPE does not have any interested or advanced options. I failed to configure the LAN to Wan. I have made the LAN to LAN work fine. But this has rendered by awesome wrt1900acs router dumb and all the advanced features and settings are rendered useless.

Comment: did you get this figured out? I think you misunderstood the terminology in my comment. The 5g CPE device doesn't need those options at all. The problem you are going to run into is carrier grade nat. (You don't have a publicly available ip number using Cellular service 99.9% of the time, some carriers will assign you one upon request for a steep charge).

Answer (score 0):

> I need to maintain my DD-WRT settings to keep my VPN and Ad-Blocking
> features working.

This needs an external IP address (lots of people have 192.168.x.y internal addressing).

So you need a static external IP address or an appearance of a static external IP address by a service like Dyn DNS.

Escalate the modem bridging question, see if the ISP can give you a different modem, or try a different ISP.

Comment: My adblocking part will work just fine, because I have the configuration built into the DDWRT router.

Comment: VPN needs an external IP address.

Comment: My ISP does not have any other CPE Modem in their product line. They do not offer any possibility to bridge the CPE 5G.

Comment: Obtaining a personal CPE from another Brand is not an option. The ISP enables 5G at device level, and sim card level. So the IMEI number range of the CPE actually enables the 5G Network support.

Comment: With regards to the VPN, I believe this part should also be just fine. Because it will have an external IP address if I can just get the 2nd router to work.